# How to return multiple Models from Service Layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Let's say I have 2 tables, `Page` and `Application`.

Page always belongs to an application, so `Application.ID = P.ApplicationID.`

I have 2 domain model classes `Page` and `Application`. Now in my Service Layer, I need to get a Page and its `Application` properties. So, how to handle this situation? Whether I need to create a composite model? I have search a lot but could not found any and I am stuck here.

Comment: Does Application not have a Pages property? thus you could return an Application object, that would have a List (maybe?) of Pages. Alternatively, yes you could create a specific return model that has two properties, an Application and a Page.

Comment: Sure why not? It seemed logical if you have an Application and a Page always belongs to an application. I read that as you have an Application object that has a List<Page> Pages property on it. If that's not the case of your current objects and you can't modify them to support that (or for some other reason it doesn't / shouldn't have a Pages property), then you are spot on with creating a composite model.

Comment: you're welcome. Posted as an answer for others seeking guidance, since it seemed to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a Page is always associated to an Application, you're application object might have a `List<Page> Pages` property. If so, then you can return your Application object, with the appropriate Page populated in that list.

If you're Application does not contain a List Pages property, it seems logical from your (short) explanation that it probably should. If you can modify the object to include a List then you are in the same position as above and you are good.

If for some reason, it does not have a List Pages property, and you cannot modify it to include one (perhaps it doesn't make sense in the bigger picture, perhaps you do not control the object), then you are right to create a simple composite class that has two properties Page and Application.